Why is dividing a uint8 numpy array by a float32 faster than explicit type conversion?
I am working with some image data so the images are represented as numpy arrays with shape (1404, 1404, 3). The image is of type np.uint8 (it has RGB values from 0 to 255)
I am wondering about the difference in speed between these 2 lines of code:
normalized_image = image.astype("float32") / 255.0 

normalized_image = image / np.float32(255)

After testing these lines on 100 different images, I got the following times for the first line of code:

As for the second line of code:

Why is the second line of code so much faster? Aren't they both technically converting the image from uint8 to float32 numpy arrays and performing vectorized division?
I tried other order of operations but this one seemed to have a big difference. Any numpy experts know the answer to this?

I see "pil_to_numpy()" in the second screen shot. What is image? Please include a [mre]. Also, do note that 255.0 is a 64-bit float, not a 32-bit float. Are the two results of the same type?

Yes, please ignore the pil_to_numpy() method. It is just np.array() under the hood. image is the image loaded as a numpy array, i described this in the second sentence of the post; sorry if it wasn't clear
I did include an example of code you can run, it is just the 2 lines of code provided in the post. I just ran some time tests to get those charts
Yes, the 2 resulting matrices are both np.float32 numpy arrays

probably a matter of cache usage and data transfer. explicit conversion creates a new temporary array. direct operation might cause code to be called that handles uint8/float32 directly. I say "probably" because I think that's the most likely explanation and because I CBA to verify it or hold a lecture on it.

Why do you think it is strange? I mean, if the question was literally the one of the title, it would be strange, indeed (but the answer to that literal question is "it is false": a conversion is faster than a division), But your real question is "why converting, then dividing is slower that dividing". The answer is then "how could it not be?"

@chrslg I think the point is both lines consist of conversion and division. The one below is probably doing it without creating temporary array as the one above does (as Christoph suggests), which makes sense

@dankal444, not exactly. The second one probably uses instruction fidivr of x86 CPU (if running on a x86 CPU. But there are probably equivalent in other CPU), to directly divide integers by a float, and get a float result, for each element. While the first version does convert integer into floats (and store them in a new array), then uses a standard fdiv to perform the division.

But even if only fdiv existed,. indeed, the simple need for a temporary array would be sufficient to explain the difference. The first algorithm would allocate a whole new array, to store img.astype(float32), then perform a division on each number of that array, to get another result array. While the second code does it in a single for loop, allocating only the result array. So tmp=malloc(); for(...i...) tmp[i] = (float)img[i]; then res=malloc(); for(...i...) res[i]=tmp[i]/255.0 for the 1st one. Vs res=malloc(); for(...i...) res[i] = ((float)img[i])/255.0 for the 2nd one. In pseudo-c

@chrslg IIUC documentation fidiv/fidivr still does conversion, just inside CPU instruction (which is great)

(note that ((float)img[i])/255.0 could be written img[i]/255.0 in C, but, that is just some pseudo-c to illustrate "convert then divide" operation, through a temporary array in the 1st case, directly in the 2nd.

@dankal444 : just try it, if you have some assembly language chain at hand. It is faster. And sure, they don't have a combinatory ad-hoc circuit to perform int/float division (anyway, that wouldn't be faster, since, converting a int to a float is just a matter of some shifting, and filling with 0). But point is, there is absolutely no reason, no hypothesis on implementation and CPU that could lead to "converting then dividing should be as fast or faster".

Is there any numpy documentation on this or code links to look at to determine how exactly this extra memory allocation is avoided?
